# A question about JavaScript object property name

Tags: javascript

I've a question about JavaScript object property name. Check out codes below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>An HTML5 document</title>
<script>
    var obj = {
        123: 'go' // 123 is not a valid JavaScript name. No error here.
    };
    var obj2 = {
        123a: 'go' // An Error occurred.
    };
</script>
```

If a JavaScript object's property name is a valid JavaScript identifier, object porperty name's quotes are not necessary.

E.g.

```
({go_go: 'go'}); // OK
({go-go: 'go'}); // Fail
```

In the codes above, `123a` is an invalid JavaScript name and it's not be quoted. So An error occurred. But `123` is also an invalid JavaScript name and also it's not quoted, why no error here? Personally I think `123` must be quoted.

Thank you!

Comment: thats javascript for ya.  I think you shold get an error for not having ; at the end of your var statements

Comment: @Matt: Nope, JavaScript has some pretty sophisticated automatic semicolon insertion; only, please don't rely on it, things can go horribly wrong when you omit semicolons in critical places.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel Exactly, I meant in my opinion it should not be automatic and should throw a syntax error when you forget them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5):

```
ObjectLiteral :
    { }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList }
    { PropertyNameAndValueList  ,}

PropertyNameAndValueList :
    PropertyAssignment
    PropertyNameAndValueList , PropertyAssignment

PropertyAssignment :
    PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
    get PropertyName ( ){ FunctionBody }
    set PropertyName ( PropertySetParameterList ){ FunctionBody }

PropertyName :  
    IdentifierName
    StringLiteral
    NumericLiteral
```

So a property name can be either an identifier name, a string or a number. `123` is a number whereas `123a` is neither of those above.

Answer (score 8):

The key portion of each key-value pair can be written as any valid JavaScript identifier, a string (wrapped in quotes) or ***a number***:

```
var x = {
    validIdentifier: 123,
    'some string': 456,
    99999: 789
};
```

See the spec: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.1.5

Answer (score 0):

`123` is not, per-se, an invalid property name.  Any property name that is not a string is typecast to a string with the `toString` method.

Comment: Nope; see Felix' answer to know what's wrong. You can only use `123a` as a `PropertyName` when you enclose that property name within quote characters; moreover, you can only access such a property using the square bracket notation (`object["123a"]`).