# Why is the '@' symbol reserved in javascript and what is its purpose?

Tags: javascript

```
var @foo = 'bar';
// SyntaxError: missing variable name.

{ '@foo' : 'bar' };
// SyntaxError: invalid label.

var obj = { '@foo' : 'bar' };
obj.@foo;
// TypeError: can't convert AttributeName to string

var obj = { '@foo' : 'bar' };
obj['@foo'];
// "bar"
```

Can anyone explain to me why the '@' symbol is not allowed to be used in variable names and what I *should* be using it for?

Comment: it is used in e4x some special kind of syntax to traverse xml

Comment: As well as you can't use `#`, `'` or `"`. It is invalid syntax for variable names.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A question about JavaScript object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006049/a-question-about-javascript-object-property-name)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not reserved or special, it's just not a valid javascript identifier character. For the same reason this works:

```
var obj = { 'foo-baz' : 'bar' };
obj['foo-baz'];
```

And this does not:

```
var obj = { 'foo-baz' : 'bar' };
obj.foo-baz;
```

Valid javascript identifiers must start with a letter or `$`, and may only contain letters, numbers, `$`, and `_`. Anything else in a property name will force you to use bracket notation.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122609/how-do-i-reference-a-javascript-object-property-with-a-hyphen-in-it).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. However, I know that the `-` symbol subtracts. What does `@` do?

Comment: @idbehold it has nothing to do with what the symbol does (`@` has no special meaning in javascript, if you're curious) - according to the [spec](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5), object keys must be either string literals, numeric literals, or identifier names. Since `@`, `-`, etc, are not allowed in identifier names, they must be wrapped in quotes to become string literals.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Perfect explanation.