# How to create a view in couchDB with a doc that has a key of "@"

Tags: javascript, json, mapreduce, couchdb

I am testing and learning CouchDB for a project. We want to load a series of JSON files into the DB. The problem I am having is the format of the JSON, as it has keys of "@". For example:

```
{
    "_id":"somestringhere",
    "@": [
           {
           "identifier":"somevalue",
           "somekey":"somevalue" 
           },
           {
           "somekey":"somevalue",
           "somekey":"somevalue"
           }
         ]
}
```

So I go to write my Map function to emit the value of the `"@"` like so:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(null, doc.@);
}
```

This does not work and throws an error, as its not a valid identifier. What gives? I don't think it's a problem with JSON. More of a javascript error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further digging I found more information on javascript identifiers.

[Why is the '@' symbol reserved in javascript and what is its purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442738/why-is-the-symbol-reserved-in-javascript-and-what-is-its-purpose)

I was then able to access that node of the JSON with:

```
function(doc) {
  emit("document": doc['@']);
}
```

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with SO. But when you find the answer to your own question, you can validate it as 'the' answer. There is no problem with that.

Comment: Shouldn't it work also without the dot (`doc['@']`)?

Comment: Not also, but only! Thanks for keeping my brain churning. I have modified my answer to remove the `.`